# bson:"-" doesn't unmarshall and ignore on insert

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have been facing some difficulties with $lookup:

My struct:

```
type Item struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Name        string          `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Description string          `json:"description" bson:"description"`
    CoverImage  bson.ObjectId   `json:"cover_image,omitempty" bson:"cover_image,omitempty"`
    GalleryList []*File
}

pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "files",
            "localField":   "cover_image",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "gallerylist",
    },
}
```

So, what I want to do is use $lookup to get structs with matching ID on collection "files" with the "cover_image" field ID.

Until here it's ok, the problem is:

If `'bson:"-"'` is on GalleryList, the pipeline don't unmarshall on the field

Ex: `GalleryList []*File 'bson:"-"'`

And I don't want GalleryList to be stored inside mongo.

Is there anything that I can to GalleryList don't be inserted with the rest of the struct.

Does I really need to remove this on the frontend or remove manually before inserting on mongo?

Thanks!

Comment: From first glance, I can tell that you overnormalized your data, unless including CoverImage is going to break the 16MB document limit. As per the exclusion, `bson:"-"` should do what you want, as unexporting the field would do, too. Maybe I do not get the actual problem.

Comment: The problem is simple, adding `bson:"-"` "$lookup" don't unmarshall to the field, so I cannot put the exclusion, therefore is saving to mongo, I only want a way to not pre-processing  the request before inserting to mongo. (removing the field mannualy)

Comment: So what you want is to have it read the field *from* mongo, but not write it *to* mongo? Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I need it to read from the other collection but I don't want to save it in the first collection. this is happening because it's in my struct without exclusion so mongo write it, but if I put the exclusion the "$lookup" don't unmarshall the field.

Comment: Basically `GalleryList []*File 'bson:"-"'`  don't unmarshall with "$lookup"and
`GalleryList []*File` unmarshall's but it's write to mongo either.

Comment: You can use $set operator to update only those fields that you want to.